# Query rule usage report for promoted results not showing counts in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-search, query-rule, promoted-results

We have configured various query rules for the promoted results in search center few months back in SharePoint online. When I try to get the Query Rule Usage by Month report, its not showing any promoted results details like Times fired, Promoted result clicks etc.

Report location: 
site setting--> Popularity and Search Reports--> Query Rule Usage by Month/Query Rule Usage by Day

Please let me know if I need to configure anything.

Thanks